# Android QBRTCSession.initPeerConnectionFactor Quickblox 2.25 audio call feature

Tags: android, android-activity, quickblox

On quickblox audio call button click, error could not find class 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.OpponentsParser', referenced from method com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel.videoChatMessageWithOpponentID is shown and application crash. It crashes a line

```
QBRTCSession newSessionWithOpponents = QBRTCClient.getInstance().createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);
```

Session unsuccessfully generated in oncreate() Activity. Which steps is missing , should i initialise QBRTCClient before calling new opponent session, if yes, how can i re-initialied QBRTCClient. Here is my log

```
   06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession.initPeerConnectionFactory(QBRTCSession.java:177)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc..<init>(QBRTCSession.java:149)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(QBRTCClient.java:130)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at .quickblox.voip.CallActivity.addConversationFragmentStartCall(CallActivity.java:666)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at .quickblox.voip.fragment.OpponentsFragment.onClick(OpponentsFragment.java:199)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jingle_peerconnection_so from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/-2]: findLibrary returned null
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    at org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.<clinit>(PeerConnectionFactory.java:39)
    06-23 14:29:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25781):    ... 16 more
    ## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 2):

To figure out how to work with quickblox webrtc module look [quickblox webrtc documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android)

What about error below:

```
On quickblox audio call button click, error could not find class 'com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.OpponentsParser', referenced from method com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBSignalChannel.videoChatMessageWithOpponentID is shown and application crash. It crashes a line
```

Looks like you use old jar file of quickblox chat module. Try to use latest jars from [updated samples project](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/jars)

Comment: latest jar does not support all previous quickblox chat system method.

Comment: Yes. Some of methods were changed and removed (most of them was deprecated earlier). If you mean classes which related with message's history, they was included in QBChatMessage class (just remove their type to QBChatMessage).